# Search for a pattern in Vim excluding some possibilities

Tags: vim

How can we search for a something in Vim, excluding some of the possibilities which the search would cover?

For example: Search for `How\s[a-z]` but the result should not include `How a` and should include `How b`, `How c`, ..., `How z`.

**UPDATE**
One possible solution to the above illustrative example is `How\s[b-z]` as pointed out by @Jonathon K, which is correct. But what I am looking for is a generic solution in which I can exclude one of the many possible solutions in a Vim search (Example 2: Exclude `ERROR` when I search for `er*`. Ad-hoc solutions could be there for this case as well :) ).

Comment: Do you have a better example?  The real solution to your excluding `How a` would be `How\s[b-z]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Example 2: Exclude ERROR when I search for `er*`. Ad-hoc solutions could be there for this case as well.

Just FYI, `er*` will not match `ERROR`. It will match any of these:

> e
>
> er
>
> errrrr
>
> errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

You're probably thinking of `ER.*`

Moving on from that...

---

You're basically looking for the `\@!` quantifier. It asserts that the previous atom *does not* match at the current position. It's also zero-width. If you wanted to search for `ER.*` but not match `ERROR`, you could do this:

```
ER\(ROR\)\@!.*
```

Or as I prefer with "magic" on (`\v`):

```
\vER(ROR)@!.*
```

Or with your first example:

```
\vHow\sa@![a-z]
```

Even though I would recommend using `[b-z]` like Jonathon pointed out :)